# Set a time goal for a Jest test

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I'm looking for a way to set a total time limit test with Jest, i.e. something like `expect(somefunction()).toTake(1000)`. I'm aware that the second parameter for the test is a timeout for async functions, but I'm specifically looking to test the performance of the entire function (both async and non async parts) and have the test pass / fail in relation to the time it took to run the function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a comment which may help you in a related issue in jest repository; https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2694#issuecomment-411499373

Also, here is the code piece from that comment.

```
it('Should create 1000 objects pretty fast', async () => {

    var start = new Date()

    // Do expensive thing 1000 times

    var after_save_all = new Date()

    expect(after_save_all.getTime() - start.getTime()).toBeLessThanOrEqual(3000);
})
```

Comment: This is a decent solution when running tests in a vacuum (i.e. no CPU load from anything else and tests don't run in parallel), as the original poster said. Thanks, I'll use this if there isn't something that would work in more complex scenarios. Also it seems like this would break if run around midnight which is funny (it doesn't take the date into account)